# How do you import config sync files in a Drupal 8 functional test?

Tags: drupal, phpunit, functional-testing, drupal-8, configuration-management

I would like to know how to import config sync files in my functional tests for modules I am testing. For instance, I have some custom content types I would like to test against, and there are a number of files in config/sync that pertain to the node modules that defines the custom content type.

```
class ArticleControllerTest extends BrowserTestBase {
    protected static $modules = ['node', 'dist_source'];
}
```

At the top of my test I define the modules which do succesfully import, but it doesn't include the config sync settings so none of my custom content types are present. How can I import these into my test environment?

Comment: Hi Thomas, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

At the beginning of testing for Drupal 8, I had the same question. After reading some documents and tutorials, I tried and know several methods:

#### `$this->configImporter()` helps import the configurations from sync to active

`$this->configImporter()` exits in `Drupal\Tests\ConfigTestTrait`. And the trait has been used in some based test classes, like `BrowserTestBase`.

However, the method doesn't work for me. Because, I used thunder installation profile. The default content exists after the profile installation was completed. Once the `$this->configImporter()` starts to import sync configurations, it encounters errors that some entity types fail to be updated, because the entities already exists.

#### Create a testing profile

*(Haven't tried)*

If the Drupal site installed by standard profile, you may try to put the sync configurations into a testing profile. And [Install Profile Generator](https://www.drupal.org/project/install_profile_generator) module may helps you create the testing profile. There is a related issue [#2788777](https://www.drupal.org/node/2788777) with config and profile

#### Put the configurations which depend on module into `config/install` or `config/optional`

*(Work for me)*

Contributed modules always put the config into `config/install` and `config/optional`. Once the module is installed, the configurations will also write into database or active storage. [Documentation - Include default configuration in your Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/include-default-configuration-in-your-drupal-8-module)

When developing configurations in module, [Configuration development](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_devel) helps export the config into `config/install` of the developed module.

If anyone has the same experience, look forward to share with us.

Comment: How did you use `::configImporter()`? `$this->configImporter()->import();` gave the error message "Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization. This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configuration, so has been rejected."

Comment: @LiamMorland The source config is empty because it's set up to pull from the "config sync store" (the filesystem), which in functional tests point to a subfolder within the temporary site created for every test, unless you have already exported the active config there.
Many test-specific modules store config in their own /config/install folder for automatic import when installed, or a /config/sync folder to be pulled in during tests by first copying them into the temp site. See `FieldIMportCreateTest` for an example.

Comment: @TwoD Thanks for your answer. Do I understand correctly that it will pull from `/config/install` in the same module as the test? Is there a way to set the directory it pulls from?

Comment: @LiamMorland Yes, and no. The specific test I mentioned indirectly pulls the config in by simply installing the module, `\Drupal::service('module_installer')->install(['field_test_config']);`. which ends up calling `\Drupal::service('config.installer')->installDefaultConfig('module', $module);`, so that is not configurable. But you can of course replicate what that last call does to install config from anywhere. In some cases at work we have site-specific tests pull a lot of config from `config/sync` instead. However, note that the more you put in, the longer it usually takes to run the test.

Comment: @TwoD Installing from `config/sync` is what I want to do. We're using `\Drupal::service('config.installer')->installOptionalConfig($config_source);`, but that only brings in some config; see my comment to another answer on this page.

Answer (score 3):

I do it in my testing base class (`extends BrowserTestBase`) in `setUp()` like this:

```
    // import config from sync
    $config_path =  '/home/rainer/src/asdent/config/sync';
    $config_source = new FileStorage($config_path);
    \Drupal::service('config.installer')->installOptionalConfig($config_source);
```

works great.

It's just like a `drush cim sync`

And provides the production config to my end-2-end automated phpunit tests in gitlab CI.

Comment: This requires at the top of the file:
`use Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage;`

Comment: This is working for things like content types. But config of `registration_role` module (and perhaps other contrib modules as well) is not coming in despite being in the config sync directory.